# Is doubting shirk?

Tags: shirk, waswasa

Assalamu alaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuhu,

I think I did a sin due to waswaas and I was like will Allah (SWT) forgive me? I know that he is Al-Ghafoor (the most- forgiving) but something in me made me have a doubt. And now I’m confused and scared if I just committed shirk. Please let me know if doubting on Allah’s name is a huge sin?

Jazakallah khair

Comment: Can someone please let me know if you know the answer. Jazakallah khair.